Does anyone know any low code or nocode packages (open-source or commercial) for load and longevity testing a mobile app?
In my research so far, I've found Jmeter, but Jmeter looks like it's for testing the services that the app are going to access. I am interested more in testing the system resource boundaries,m like low CPU and memory in the device, as well as longevity tests where it can run the same tasks in an automated fashion for a long period of time.

If you're looking for a way to assess the performance of the mobile application itself - the best option is sticking to profiler tools provided by mobile operating system vendors:

Android Studio Profiler
Xcode Instruments usage to improve app performance

In case you want to simulate hundreds/thousands of mobile applications concurrently accessing backend/database you can go for a load testing tool, for example Apache JMeter doesn't require any programming language knowledge, check out Load Testing Apps for Mobile Made Easy article for more information on the concept
